# How to print path of a graph (c programming)

Tags: c, data-structures

Suppose I want to print path from graph structure.
I want to print path from B to G: it is B A E G but when i run my program it's also print D too. I use traverse breadth first like this

```
void traverseBreadFirst(VERTEX_t* pVertex,void (*vfunction)(VERTEX_T))
{
    VERTEX_T * pCurrent = NULL;
    VERTEX_T * pAdjacent = NULL;
    queueClear();
    colorAll(WHITE);
    pVertex->color = GRAY;
    enqueue(pVertex);
    while(queueSize()>0)
    {
        pCurrent = (VERTEX_T*)dequeue();
        if(pCurrent->color != BLACK)
        {
            (*vFunction)(pCurrent);
            pCurrent->color = BLACK;
            ADJACENT_T *pRef = pCurrent->adjacentHead;
            while(pRef != NULL)
            {
                pAdjacent = (VERTEX_T*) pRef->pVertex;
                if(pAdjacent->color != BLACK)
                {
                    pAdjacent->color = GRAY;
                    enqueue(pAdjacent);
                }
                pRef = pRef->next;
            }
        }
    } //end while queue has data
}
```

And this my print path function(it's not working correctly and it is recursive)

```
void printVertexPath(VERTEX_T *pVertex)
{
    if(pVertex->next!=NULL)
        printf("%s to %s",pVertex->name,pVertex->data);
}

void printPath(char *key1,char *key2)
{
    VERTEX_T *pCheck = NULL;
    VERTEX_T *pStart = findVertexByKey(key1,&pCheck);
    VERTEX_T *pVertex= findVertexByKey(key2,&pCheck);
    if(pStart == NULL || pEnd == NULL)
        {printf("Either of vertex is not found");}
    else
        {traverseBreadthFirst(pStart,&printVertexPath);}
}
```

Do you guys have any suggestion on how to do this properly? I would appreciate it. This is my first question so sorry for my bad grammar.

Comment: Please format your code so it becomes readable.

Comment: Sorry this is my first question. What do you mean by format my code?

Comment: You should explain the VERTEX_T struct and tell us how you fill fill it. Giving us an example with data would be even better. Fast remarks: pEnd isn't used by the traverseBreadFirst function so how could it find the path? And also there's no recursivity in your code.

Comment: You mean like what is inside VERTEX_T structure? And i change pEnd to pVertex

Comment: @asiandudeCom I "formatted" your code, but it may have lost the edit you recently made, if so sorry, please try again.

Comment: You don't give a picture or list of vertex pairs of your graph. What path is being printed or does it merely print B A E G with a D somewhere, because you haven't associated any weights on each vertex to find the cheapest solution. If you were to leave your program to produce all results you'd probably B A E G , but no where in your logic do you attempt to establish shortest or cheapest path

Comment: @rhubarbdog I can't put a picture in this forum it's say i don't have enough reputation. How you going to establish shortest way by Dijkstra algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

When you visit each node in the `traverseBreadFirst` function: you have these lines:

```
   if(pAdjacent->color != BLACK)
   {
           pAdjacent->color = GRAY;
           enqueue(pAdjacent);
   }
```

You need to add something in there to link `pAdjacent` back to `pCurrent`. For example: change it like this:

```
   if(pAdjacent->color != BLACK)
   {
           pAdjacent->color = GRAY;
           pAdjacent->backwards = pCurrent;
           enqueue(pAdjacent);
   }
```

Of course, if you use this exact code then you need to add `VERTEX_T *backwards` into the `VERTEX_T` structure. But you could do it differently (for example: using a hashmap) just as long as at the end you can figure out what `backwards` was for each node when that part of the function was running.

Then to print: start at the end and build list by following it backwards, then when you reach the start you can print forwards.